# Will simply adding a 'Allow Cross Origin Requests' to my node app work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, heroku

**My Goal**

I'm trying to make a **frontend web scraper**.

I had the idea of setting up a node app that had a dynamic route that used Request *(the NPM package)* to scrape pages and displayed them as it's own.

Then my JS plugin would add an *invisible iframe* to whatever page it's used on with of `'nodeapp.com/[URL-TO-SCRAPE]'`.

Then use the inter page `getElementById()` function to get the text.

**So my question is**
If i put my app on heroku, im able to get the page wich have the header of `Allow Cross Origin Request`, i know i can't use `getElementById()` across multiple origins

Answer (score 0):

`Allow Cross Origin Request` is not for cross domain **javascript** but for cross domain **request**.

`Allow Cross Origin Request` allow the javascript on A.com to access resource url on B.com. But javascript on A.com can not manipulate iframe which showing B.com, in any case.